# Implementing a query function with undeclared number of parameters?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm developing a server/client application in C#. In the earlier phases of development I was writing SQL codes each time and it caused spaghetti code. Now I'm trying to make it clean. My question is: How can I write a general query generator function with dynamic parameters?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl(line, name, firstvalue, secondvalue)" +
                "VALUES(@line, @name, @value, @secondvalue)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line", comboBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", comboBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondvalue", comboBox6.Text);
            cmd.Connection = Db.Db;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Db.Close();
        }
}
```

But I want to convert it into:

```
        public void query(string commandText, params string[] parameters)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
//In this part, there can be lots of different queries and how can assign each parameter to relevant values
//Is there any change to assign them in order.              
    }
```

Comment: Instead of building your own, why not investigate a lightweight [ORM like Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: @StuartLC thanks for recommendation but I am trying to write it to improve myself.

Comment: Seeing button_click in the same method/class as SqlCommand gives me the shivers.  Please read up on "Layered architecture"  Here is an oldie but goodie as an INTRO : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmeier/2008/09/06/layers-and-components/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you insist on *implementing* such a routine (usually we use *ORM*) you have to *parse* the `commandText`; the simplest (but not the *best*) implementation is *regular expressions* (we `Match` parameter *name* within `commandText`, then `Zip` it with its *value* from `parameters`):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public void query(string commandText, params string[] parameters) {
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand()) {
    command.Connection = myConnection; //TODO: put the right connection here
    command.CommandText = commandText;

    var prms = Regex
      .Matches(commandText, @"\b@[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\b") 
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Zip(parameters, (match, value) => new {
         name = match.Value,
         value
       });

    foreach(var prm in prms) 
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue(prm.name, prm.value);

    // Just execute; we have nothing to read (ExecuteReader)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
  }
}
```

**Edit:** If you want / ready to specify parameters' *names*, not only values you can try `Tuple`s: for **c# 7.0+**

```
public void query(string commandText, params (string, object)[] parameters) {
   ...
   foreach (var prm in parameters) 
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue(prm.Item1, prm.Item2);

   ...
}
```

usage

```
query(sql, 
  ("@line", comboBox4.Text),
  ("@name", textBox2.Text),
  ("@id", 123),             // please, note integer value
  ("@money", 456.78d), 
   ... 
);
```

for **C# 6.0-**:

```
public void query(string commandText, params Tuple<string, object>[] parameters) {
   ...
   foreach (var prm in parameters) 
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue(prm.Item1, prm.Item2);

   ...
}

...

query(sql, 
  Tuple.Create("@line", comboBox4.Text),
  Tuple.Create("@name", textBox2.Text),
   ... 
);
```

Comment: I solved the problem, but this would be the best answer. It is much more optimized, thanks four your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with database parameters and set all values in it. Use Entity framework to do the rest or read from object when assigning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and here is the solution. We will store them in the same array. So the parameters array will be:

```
parameters[0] = "@line"
parameters[1] = line
parameters[2] = "@name"
parameters[3] = name
```

and while posting them into `AddWithValue()` function

```
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length;)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i++] as string,parameters[i++]);
        }
```

and we should call the query function when needed like this,

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO tbl(line, name, firstvalue, secondvalue)" +
                "VALUES(@line, @name, @value, @secondvalue)";
query("@line", line, "@name", name, "@value", firstvalue, "secondvalue", secondvalue);
```

Comment: If you are ready to pass parameters' *names* (not only *value*s) I suggest using `Tuple<string, object>[] parameters` or `(string, object)[] parameters` declaration for the `parameters`

Comment: I love this website, each day people teach me some thing that I already know however do not realize while coding. It is much better than storing different kinds of objects in the same array. Thanks a lot ! @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 0):

**Function Body**

```
public class Database
{
        public string executeScaler(string commandText, bool isStoredProcedure, Dictionary<string, object> dictParams = null)
        {
            string result = "";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = ConnectionStrings.GetConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);

            if (isStoredProcedure)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (dictParams != null)
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> rec in dictParams)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + rec.Key, rec.Value);

            try
            {
                result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

**Calling Function**

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("Email", obj.Email);
dict.Add("Password", obj.Password);
Database objDB = new Database();
objDB.executeScaler("RegisterAccount", true, dict);
```